# Opening JQuery dialog box onclick of dynamically created linkbuttons

Tags: jquery

I have created a blog. A specific group member can chat in that blog. Each comment has a dynamically created LinkButton (`"edit"->text`)

Upon clicking on the edit linkbutton, I want a dialog box to pop up. I tried a lot but unable to proceed. Please help.

Following is the piece of code on how I am trying this.

in *.cs* file : (this is how I dynamically created the link button) (I have used LinkButtons class in my jquery.

```
LinkButton lnkUpdateComment = new LinkButton();
lnkUpdateComment.ID = "" + objBridgeNotes.BridgeNotesId;
lnkUpdateComment.Text = "edit";
lnkUpdateComment.Attributes.Add("class", "lnkButtons");
lnkUpdateComment.Click += new EventHandler(lnkUpdateComment_Click);
```

*.js* file:

```
$(document).ready(function()  {

$(".lnkButtons").live("click", function()  {
$("#divEditComment").dialog("option", "title", "Edit the Comment");
$("#divEditComment").dialog("open");
return true;
});

$(function () {
var dlg = $("#divEditComment").dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    show: "blind",
    hide: "blind",
    //height: 450,
    minWidth: 400,
    //position: ['right', 210],
    buttons: {
        "Update Note": function () {

            var Updates = btnSubmitComment.replace(/_/g, '$');
            __doPostBack(Updates, '');
        }
    }
});
dlg.parent().appendTo(jQuery("form:first"));
});

});
```

in *.aspx* file:

```
    <div id="divEditComment">
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="updComments" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div>
            <table width="100%" style="text-align: center">
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <div id="divComments" runat="server">
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </ContentTemplate>

</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you want a popup window on click of the edit button of each comment right?. If click function is not working , just check version of jquery you are using because jquery 1.9 version onward 'live' has been removed. Use the on() method instead.

> $(".lnkButtons").on("click", function()  { });